# Como colocar mascara para Nextel em um <input> com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu gostaria de colocar mascara em um `<input>` que espera o formato *Nextel*:

```
<input type="text" name="nextel">
```

O problema que conforme o [site](http://www.nextel.com.br/atendimento/radio-como-usar) o formato do Nextel é este:

[image: nextel formato]

- **Urban:** 2 dígitos
- **Frota:** 1 a 7 dígitos
- **ID:** 2 a 5 dígitos

O seja o Frota e o ID tem números quantidade variante, tenho usado o plugin http://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin, não sei bem como fazer por exemplo de 1 a 7 para frota.

No entanto procuro solução com qualquer outro *plugin* ou até mesmo em Javascript puro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode colocar três campos de tipo numérico lado a lado, pode não ser a melhor solução mas não deixa de ser uma alternativa.

Por meio dos atributos `min` e `max` pode-se controlar quantos dígitos o campo pode receber: se o máximo são dois, então o usuário pode entrar com qualquer valor entre 10 e 99.

Eu vejo isso como algo bom do ponto de vista da usabilidade, afinal se o campo só aceita números nada melhor que abrir o teclado numérico quando o usuário acessar o site pelo celular.

```html
<div id='nextel'>
  <input type='number' min='10' max='99'>
  <input type='number' min='1'  max='9999999'>
  <input type='number' min='10' max='99999'>
</div>
```

Por mais que sejam três campos, pegar o valor não é problema nenhum. Basta um `querySelectorAll('#nextel input')` concatenando o `value` de cada um.

---

#### # snippet:

```js
function getNextelNumber(){
  let nextel = '';
  for(let input of document.querySelectorAll('.nextel input'))
    nextel += input.value;
  return nextel;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  alert(getNextelNumber());
});
```

```css
.nextel input {
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
  outline:none;
  width: 7ch
}

.nextel input:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-bottom-color: red
}

/* Removendo a aparência padrão do campo 'number'. */
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='nextel'>
  <input type='number' min='10' max='99'>
  <input type='number' min='1'  max='9999999'>
  <input type='number' min='10' max='99999'>
</div>

<br><br>
<button>Qual é meu Nextel?</button>
```

Comment: **Nota**: Essa solução não é *cross-browser* ([**ainda**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number)).

Comment: Pode trocar o `max` por `maxlength`, não vou aceitar a resposta ainda pois tenho esperanças de fazer em um input, todavia é a solução que estou usando e por isso merece +1 :) (e depois vou lançar uma recompensa)

Comment: `maxlength` só funciona em input de tipos [`text, email, search, password, tel` ou `url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) :/ tem que ser na gambiarra do "valor máximo permitido" mesmo.

Comment: a bom saber, mas era devido ao problema de não ser cross-browser. Por exemplo seria melhor ter o maxlength ao menos, mesmo que o min não funcione ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o validador do browser com o atributo `pattern`. Isto combinado com um `placeholder` pode ser uma forma elegante de resolver o problema.

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Nextel: <input type="text" name="nextel" pattern="\d{2}[*]{1}\d{1,7}[*]{1}\d{2,5}" title="Insira um nextel valido" placeholder="ZZ*XXXXXXX*YYYYY">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Cuidado se colocar `pattern` não funciona para Safari e outros mobile. (veja http://html5pattern.com/)

Comment: Obrigado Bruno! Mas pattern não é a mesma coisa que mascara.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah ja percebi a mascara que estava a referir. Pode usar o placeholder? Ou quer algo mais explicito?

Comment: @BrunoCosta é uma boa sugestão combinar placeholder+pattern, todavia vou esperar outras respostas

Answer (score 0):

Utilize plugin **VanillaMasker** é javascript puro sem jquery

```js
function inputHandler(masks, max, event) {
    var c = event.target;
    var v = c.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var m = c.value.length > max ? 1 : 0;
    VMasker(c).unMask();
    VMasker(c).maskPattern(masks[m]);
    c.value = VMasker.toPattern(v, masks[m]);
}

var telMask = ['(99) 9999-99999', '(99) 99999-9999'];
var tel = document.querySelector('input[attrname=telephone1]');
VMasker(tel).maskPattern(telMask[0]);
tel.addEventListener('input', inputHandler.bind(undefined, telMask, 14), false);
```

```css
div {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}  
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: black;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-masker/1.1.0/vanilla-masker.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label for="tel">Telefone</label>
<input attrname="telephone1" type="text">
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu disse Nextel e não formato de telefone, isso seria uma mascara para o telefone associado ao Nextel, o que eu quero é uma masta para o `Urban*Frota*ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei outra forma de fazer isto com o [jquery input mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask). Ao contrário do plugin que mencionou, este permite que o utilizador clique no próximo campo da mascara, a partir do momento em que a atual esteja válida.

```js
 $('input[name=nextel]').inputmask("\d{2}-\d{1,7}-\d{2,5}");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.1/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Nextel: <input type="text" name="nextel">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zk0xktx/)

Comment: Quando for usar o stacksnippet sempre adicione as libs juntos, se não o exemplo não funciona.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Se calhar não o diva ter usado, foi por isso que adicionei um ink para o jsfiddle.

Comment: BrunoCosta é preferivel manter os códigos no site, links podem "quebrar", se o stacksnippet já faz o serviço realmente usar jsfiddle é desnecessário, eu só uso jsfiddle quando preciso de alguma funcionalidade que o StackSnippet não suporta ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Veja o que eu penso sobre [essa história dos links quebrarem](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5267/a-mensagem-passada-pela-comunidade-sobre-os-links-nas-respostas-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-a-mais-cor)

Comment: Acho que não entendeu o problema vai além disso e já foi discutido várias vezes no META, eu até entendo o seu ponto de vista, mas veja bem, eu sou um visitante, eu posso testar o código diretamente aqui no site, porque eu ainda tenho que clicar para acessar um recurso externo? Não é a Stack Exchange que esta evangelizando algo, foi o que o usuários desde o ano de 2012 andam notando, se frequentar o site SOen notará vários links antigos quebrados (geralmente respostas de 2009 ~ 2012). A SE não decidiu nada, foram uma grande parte dos usuários mais participativos que notaram o problema ;)